VS Code Language Client - Error while setting workspace folder in ClientOptions
I am trying to start LS for each workspace folder. When I try to set the workspace folder in the ClientOptions like this lsp-multi-server-sample, the workspaceFolders property (a boolean) in the workspace client capabilities is set to null in the client capabilities. Is there any other configuration I need to set in order to make it a boolean instead of null?.
I need to get the workspacefodlers property value as a boolean.
